# XML Feed Updating MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, xml

```
$time=date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/feed.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
$returned=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml=simplexml_load_string($returned);

if (!$xml=="") {
foreach($xml as $lists){

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','database') or die();
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*) as numrecords FROM db_1 WHERE username='".$lists->username."' LIMIT 1") or die (); 
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($row['numrecords'] >= 1)
{  
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE db_1 SET time='".$time."', subject='".$lists->subject."', views='".$lists->views."' WHERE username='".$lists->username."' LIMIT 1"); 
}
else 
{
$entry="INSERT INTO `db_1` (`id`, `time`, `username`, `subject`, `views`) VALUES ('', '".$time."', '".$lists->username."', '".$lists->subject."', '".$lists->views."');";
mysqli_query($con, $entry);
}
mysqli_close($con);

} }
exit;
```

Hi,

Script is called via a cronjob every x minutes.

Code will work perfectly for days and then will randomly mess up and change all the time & subjects to the same time/subject even on records it shouldn't be updating..

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If code works then it must be the data. Likely the XML changes with the *randomness*.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: I think you solved it! The subject field has emojis, other languages, all sorts of odd characters, etc. Some users subject is causing it to mess up.. I have another site using the same code and xml feed and it didn't mess up today. Its selecting a different set of usernames from the feed. I'll sanitize it.

Comment: Don't sanitize it, using prepared statements allows this sort of problem not to happen.  Also, you can open the database connection before the loop and prepare the statements then just execute with the row specific data inside the loop, close the connection after the loop.  It should run a lot quicker as well.

Comment: @DancinJasper A question for you.  After your $con=mysqli_connect(….) WHAT is the data content of $con for the id returned from MySQL?  The PHP manual just says id is returned.  Need to know if this is PROCESS ID, Thread ID,  Server ID or whatever it is, it has a practical NAME.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @NigelRen After the $con=mysqli_connect(….) WHAT is the data content of $con for the id returned from MySQL? The PHP manual just says id is returned. Need to know if this is PROCESS ID, Thread ID, Server ID or whatever it is, the data has a practical NAME. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @WilsonHauck if you have a particular question, please ask a new question rather than add bits in a comment, I'm sure you will get a fuller answer than can be given here.

Comment: Great idea.  Thanks, Wilson